# Would it be possible to give a bioengineered creature an AI powered mind that could allow it to act like a person?

Tags: biology, bioengineering

Could a bioengineered creature be implanted with an AI chip in it’s brain/nervous system to make it be able to act like a person in ways like talking, manipulating complex tools with its “fingers”, wielding weapons, etc.?

To clarify some details, imagine a creature has been bioengineered to suit a specific purpose, such as warfare.  It would be desirable for these creatures to be able to make autonomous decisions, operate weaponry, communicate with human commanders, etc.  So the humans that bioengineer these creatures also implant an AI chip into their brain and nervous system to give them the ability to do these things.  Would it be possible for an AI chip to give these creatures these abilities?  And if so, would there be any body design considerations for the AI chips to be able to communicate with the body?

Comment: We can easily bioengineer creatures which are able to act like persons in ways like talking, manipulating complex tools, and wielding weapons. About 385,000 of them are brought into the world every day. They are called children. No AI chip needed. Whatever the AI chip does, it will be over and above just acting like a person. (And, most importantly, I don't see the connection between bioengineering something and having  an AI chip fused inside; biology cannot make microchips.)

Comment: @AlexP I’m talking about creatures that have been bioengineered with certain physical traits that make them better for certain situations.  For example, natural armor and greater speed and strength than what humans possess, etc.  Yet they should be able to have a level of autonomy in the battlefield, capable of making quick decisions on the fly, and communicate with human commanders, etc.

Comment: Bioengineering is only specific to the particular thing I’m considering applying this tech to.  This could apply to ordinary creatures as well technically.  I don’t view bioengineering as necessary for this technology, I’m just asking about bioengineered creatures because that’s the type of creature I’d be applying the technology to, so the creatures could be bioengineered in ways to be able to imitate certain human capabilities with body design such as grasping things like a human would, etc.

Comment: What are you looking for in an answer here? Technically the answer to the question as you've phrased it could just be "yes".

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I’m asking if this would be theoretically possible with real-world science, and if it is, if there would be any special considerations that would have to be taken into account for the design of the “host” body to be able to communicate with the chip.

Comment: I think you still need to clarify what "a bioengineered creature" means, exactly. What kind of creature are you talking about? What kind of bioengineering are you referring to? How do you imagine implanting an AI chip will help with their activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No one knows**

(All of this is too long for a comment and is straying into answer territory.)

First, there's no such thing as general AI yet.  Computing experts are divided on whether there ever will be.  So, the assumption that it is possible to have an AI, let alone one that fits on a chip small enough to be implanted in a brain, is an unknown (although plenty of people with strong opinions will argue one way or the other).

Second, while there are exciting developments in interfaces between nerves and IT connectors for bionic ears, eyes and control of artificial limbs, we certainly are not at the point where we can plug a chip into a creature and drive it around like a biological drone.  We could probably design something today that would give commands relatively easily - just plug it into an implanted speaker and train the creature to follow the commands it hears - but it would be giving directions rather than direct control.  Direct control is maybe something that could be achieved eventually, but...

Why?  Putting this up as a frame challenge - computers are good at talking to other machine components, brains are good at controlling bodies, so why fight to do it the hard way?  If the aim is to have something controlled by a computer then give it a robot body.  If the aim is to have a biological body then provide it with a brain that will let it do what is required.

Mixing biological and mechanical/electronic components means that there is a biological element that cannot just be left on the shelf until it is required, it needs to be constantly fed and exercised.  The biological part is also vulnerable to disease and there are limits to how quickly replacements can be grown.  Then there are machine components that cannot be easily swapped out when hardware is damaged or a new version is available, surgery is required.  Then there's the mixed power supply - the biological parts need carbs while the machine bit needs electricity.

In summary, no one knows if what you are proposing will be possible in the future, it definitely cannot be done today.  So you can write your story to include meat bodies being puppetted by computers if you wish.  However, it is worth considering whether it makes sense to try this approach rather than just building robots.